# working with bitmap in c

Tags: c, bitmap, bmp

This is my first time working with bitmaps, and I've gotten pretty much most of what i need figured out already. I just need to figure out how to

1) print the first 16 pixels

Please help :) I am trying get a good grasp of working with the bmp format.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) {
    unsigned char fileMarker1;
    unsigned char fileMarker2;
    unsigned int   bfSize;
    uint16_t unused1;
    uint16_t unused2;
    unsigned int   imageDataOffset;
} FILEHEADER;

typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) {
    unsigned int   biSize;
    int            width;
    int            height;
    uint16_t planes;
    uint16_t bitPix;
    unsigned int   biCompression;
    unsigned int   biSizeImage;
    int            biXPelsPerMeter;
    int            biYPelsPerMeter;
    unsigned int   biClrUsed;
    unsigned int   biClrImportant;
} INFOHEADER;

typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) {
    unsigned char  b;
    unsigned char  g;
    unsigned char  r;
} IMAGE;

int main(void) {
    FILEHEADER fh;
    INFOHEADER ih;
    FILE *img = fopen("sample.bmp", "rb");
    fread(&fh, sizeof(unsigned char), sizeof(FILEHEADER), img);
    fread(&ih, sizeof(unsigned char), sizeof(INFOHEADER), img);
    printf("width: <%d>\nheight: <%d>\n", ih.width, ih.height);
    printf("planes: <%d>\n", ih.planes) ;

    printf("Bits per pixel: <%d>", ih.bitPix );



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do know what all the fields in the structures are for? Because the bits per pixels is right there. As for the actual image data, just continue reading the file.

Comment: I totally missed that! Now that you pointed it out, I noticed that was exactly what bitPix was for. Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean to print a pixel? You can't just issue a printf and have 16 pixels of bitmap display to your terminal. Do you have an output format in mind for representing the first 16 pixels worth of data?

Comment: Sorry, I meant printing the first 16 pixels as numerical values ( like Hex values, or whatever works best).